# I am trying to redirect a page that is in localhost

Tags: redirect, nginx, localhost

I have a localhost and need to redirect a page that is in it. Example
The page I want to access outside of localhost is: localhost:1880/ui

I made a small redirect with the NGINX:

```
server{
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 $scheme://localhost:1880$request_uri;
}
```

But then I realized that I can not access this network page outside the localhost, because this IP is bound to it. I would like to know how I could see this page (localhost: 1880/ui) outside the internal network and already with this redirect I did.

Thank you all.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  You realize a redirect is just that, right?  It's a pointer to a new location, not a proxy.

Comment: Sorry, Brad. 
I do not know very well the terms on this subject, because I started now.
Yes, I realized this only after writing this little code. I wrote it thinking that I would get access to the page (192.168.7.2:1880/ui) outside the local network, but I was only able to access it locally.
What I really want is this page can be accessed outside the local network.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with redirects.  You'll need to forward in a port from your router.

Comment: I made the forward on port 80 to 1880, but as you can see, I need the address to be specific on port 1880/ui

Comment: Then forward `1880`...